# I cant connect to my database using mysql_connect(. Please help me

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Im just learning and....

It just wont connect is there something stupid that im doing wrong?

**Add.php**

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("db517452461.db.1and1.com","dbo517452461","******") or die
 (mysql_error());
    echo "Oops ";
    mysql_select_db("admin") or die (mysql_error());
    echo "Ooops  ";

$ref= ($_POST['ref']);
$firstname = ($_POST['firstname']);

mysql_query("insert admin set ref='".$ref."', firstname='".$firstname."'");
echo "<script>alert('Record successfuly saved.');window.location.href='paragview.php';
</script>";
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="border:1px solid;">

<form action="add.php" method="post">
Ref: <input type="text" name="ref"><br>
Firstname <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Ive checked my host, username and password over and over again.

SShttp://i.cubeupload.com/FTYOhp.jpg

Comment: What error is it giving you?

Comment: Please, if you're just starting to learn PHP, learn using the MySQLi or PDO extensions with prepared statements and bind variables, rather than learning using the old, deprecated MySQL extension

Comment: Just the message you would expect if the user name or password was wrong.

Oops Access denied for user 'dbo517452461'@'%' to database 'admin'

thanks ill look into MySQLi after this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database name is something else rather than the one mentioned in the image.
Change this line:

```
mysql_select_db("admin") or die(mysql_error());
```

To:

```
mysql_select_db("db517452461") or die(mysql_error());
```

*As a side note, I recommend you to use mysqli or PDO as  mysql is now deprecated.*

Comment: I cant upvote yet im too new